# Problem getting Layout form to other page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

use a _layout cshtml to get all the same start screen. It works on the index page but when i go to the next the css of bootstrap is missing. I added a bootstrap layout but know it doesnt do the layout on the next screen. I could also send you the zip if you want with all the code. The index false exist out only the layout page without any content when you go to an other page you get the text of the layout but not the bootstrap css.

Bootstrap template: https://bootstrapmade.com/flattern-multipurpose-bootstrap-template/

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Project</title>


        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif:400,400italic,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/jcarousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Theme skin -->
        <link href="skins/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div class="container ">
                <!-- end toggle link -->
                <div class="row nomargin">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <div class="headnav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Registreer"><i class="icon-user"></i>Registreer</a></li>
                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Login" data-toggle="modal">Inloggen</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><img src="img/logo_kraan.jpg" alt="" class="logo" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span10">
                        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top ">
                            <div class="navigation">
                                <nav>
                                    <ul class="nav topnav">
                                        <li class="">
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</i></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Statuten">Statuten</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Bestuur">Raad van bestuur</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Seminaries">Seminaries</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ESCL">Over ESCL</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#">Opdrachten <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu bold">
                                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="OverheidsOpdrachten">OverheidsOpdrachten</a></li>
                                                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="PrivateOpdrachten">Private Opdrachten</a></li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Forum">forum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end navigation -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
        </header>
    </div>

   @* <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />*@

    <div class="flex-container">
        @RenderBody()
       

    </div>


        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jcarousel/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
        <script src="js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
        <script src="js/portfolio/jquery.quicksand.js"></script>
        <script src="js/portfolio/setting.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
        <script src="js/animate.js"></script>

        <!-- Template Custom JavaScript File -->
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

       
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>


    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
        <div class="widget">
          <h5 class="widgetheading">Browse pages</h5>
          <ul class="link-list">
            <li><a href="#">About our company</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Meet our team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Explore our portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Get in touch with us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <div class="widget">
          <h5 class="widgetheading">Important stuff</h5>
          <ul class="link-list">
            <li><a href="#">Press release</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms and conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Career center</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Flattern forum</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
     

      <div class="span4">
        <div class="widget">
          <h5 class="widgetheading">Get in touch with us</h5>
          <address>
            <strong>Flattern studio, Pte Ltd</strong><br>
            Springville center X264, Park Ave S.01<br>
            Semarang 16425 Indonesia
          </address>
          <p>
            <i class="icon-phone"></i> (123) 456-7890 - (123) 555-7891 <br>
            <i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i> email@domainname.com
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sub-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="copyright">
            <p>
              <span>&copy;BVBR-ABDC</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <ul class="social-network">
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Facebook"><i class="icon-facebook icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Twitter"><i class="icon-twitter icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Linkedin"><i class="icon-linkedin icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Pinterest"><i class="icon-pinterest icon-square"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="Google plus"><i class="icon-google-plus icon-square"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: The footer need to be inside the body above the scripts tag.

Comment: dit that but it is still the same

Comment: Is the path to js and css correct?

Comment: You need to check if the scripts and styles are uploaded in browser.

Comment: yes, on one page all the css and js works

Comment: it gives en error ont some scripts 404

Comment: There is the your problem check the path of these files.